# Why AccessViolationException cannot be caught by .NET4.0

Tags: c#, c++, access-violation

It is really interesting that the following C# code will crash on .NET4.0 but work fine on .NET2.0.

**C# code**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ExceptionTest();
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error !!!");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("badapp")]
    private static extern int ExceptionTest();
}
```

**C++ code**

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int ExceptionTest()
{
    IUnknown* pUnk = NULL;
    pUnk->AddRef();
    return 0;
}
```

If compiling the above C# code against .NET2.0, everything works fine. Only compiling it against .NET4.0 will make it crash at runtime.

I'm suspecting that system exception catch mechanism has been changed since .NET4.0. Any ideas?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes, it changed in .NET 4. You cannot catch exceptions that indicate a corrupted state. This is because there's pretty much no guarantee that you can do anything at all when a corrupted state exception is thrown. There is practically no reason to want a process with corrupted state to continue executing.

For compatibility with older code, you can change this behaviour by adding the [`legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638517.aspx) element to app.config.

You can also do it on a case-by-case basis by marking methods where you want to catch these exceptions with the [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute.aspx).

Comment: I'd been chasing this issue for a week! The one thing I can usefully do with my corrupted state is restart. Its a console app that *should* be running 24hrs a day. Now it will.

Comment: @Andiih unless the corrupted bits are the code that would restart it. I would use external watchdogs for this purpose.

Comment: Thx. We have an external watchdog too (have had for some time), but this enables a much quicker restart where its possible to do it.

Answer (score 4):

```
    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
    public static unsafe int LenghtPoint(this IntPtr point)
    {
        //por optimizar
        byte* bytePoint = (byte*)point.ToPointer();
        byte auxByte;
        int length = 1;
        bool encontrado = false;
        while (!encontrado)
        {

            try
            {

                auxByte = bytePoint[length];
                length++;
            }
            catch (System.AccessViolationException)
            {
                length--;
                encontrado = true;

            }
        }
        return length;
    }
```