# ExecuteNonQuery() exception not caught by try-catch

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, sybase, access-violation

I am having a problem with a database call that throws an `AccessViolationException` when I call `ExecuteNonQuery()`. The call is enclosed in a `try-catch` block but the exception is never caught. Instead, I get an entry about it in the Windows Event log. Is there a way of catching this exception in code?

```
IDbCommand cmd = ...
cmd.CommandText = "...";
try
{
    var results = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Writeline("Caught exception: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` can throw an `AccessViolationException` if an underlying driver crashes in native mode. Starting with the .NET Framework 4, managed code no longer catches these types of exceptions in catch blocks. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581202/why-accessviolationexception-cannot-be-caught-by-net4-0).

The solution is to either set the `<legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy>` [element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638517.aspx)'s **enabled** attribute to **true** in App.config, or to apply the `[System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute]` [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute.aspx) to the method containing the try-catch block.

Comment: Holy crap, thanks for this, I had no idea. My company is slowly porting code from 3.5 to 4 so we'll most likely run into this issue. On the other hand what can make the driver crash?

Comment: Bugs in unmanaged driver code (memory leaks, etc) in general, which is particularly likely if you are using old drivers.