# Not able to catch the exception system.accessviolationexception using c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, exception, dll

I wrote a window service which will convert files from XXX to XXX using [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) DLL, but when `system.accessviolationexception` occurs i am not able to catch these exception even though i have `try` and `catch` block.

But after some time my service automatically crashes down and it will write the logs in event viewer.

> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException

```
try 
{
    PDFNet.PDF.Convert.ToHtml(doc, htmlSourceFolderName, options);
} 
catch (System.AccessViolationException avex) 
  {
    logMgr.Error(avex.StackTrace);
  }
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    logMgr.Error(avex.StackTrace);
}
```

Is there any way so that i can get the desired result.

Comment: Showing us the appropriate code in question would be jolly helpful good sir. [mcve]

Comment: try
{
PDFNet.PDF.Convert.ToHtml(doc, htmlSourceFolderName, options);
}
catch(System.AccessViolationException avex)
 logMgr.Error(avex.StackTrace);
)
catch(Exception ex)
{
 logMgr.Error(avex.StackTrace);
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why AccessViolationException cannot be caught by .NET4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581202/why-accessviolationexception-cannot-be-caught-by-net4-0)

Comment: Is this an XY problem? Perhaps your p-invoke signature is incorrect?  If you fix it then you won't get such exeptions

Comment: Is it possible if i use .NET 4.5

Comment: .NET 4.0 and later are all bound by the same rules regarding catching `AccessViolationException` as far as I'm aware, especially as .NET 4.5 still runs within the .NET 4.0 _runtime_.

Answer (score 1):

Catching `AccessViolationException` has not been possible *in general* since .NET 4.0 was released.

This is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12581291/1064169

Comment: Is it possible if i use .NET 4.5

Comment: "_Since_" meaning "versions 4 and later", so _in general_, no. Why don't you read the MSDN documentation linked to in the other question's answer?